# Process synchronization for web application automation testing

Tags: selenium, automation

We are using selenium to do automation on our web application. We have knowledge of CUIT.In CUIT we have process synchronization like WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads,WaitForReadyLevel.UIThread.I want to know is there any way to achieve similar functionality using selenium?
I need some process synchronization after every step in my script for web application or is there any external APIs to achieve this.

Regards,
Raj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using this process in our automation scripts to check whether process is busy or not.Hope this piece of code gives you a idea for your requirement.

```
  bool isSync = true;
while (isSync)
            {
                using (PerformanceCounter pcProcess = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time",ProcessName))
                {
                    pcProcess.NextValue();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    if (!IsProcessRuning()) return rc;

                    double pct = pcProcess.NextValue();
                    if (pct == 0.0)
                        isSync = false;

                }
            }
```

Regards,

Nagasree.